# How to find the path to ImageMagick config files

Tags: imagemagick, rmagick

I'm attempting to load a ICM color profile file that is stored with the main ImageMagick config files (colors.xml, etc.) using RMagick.  I want to make sure that I always provide the correct path to the file across deployments using slightly different ImageMagick setups and/or versions. Is there a way to find to get this location from ImageMagick (something like Magick-config)?

This is what I have now, but it seems brittle:

```
MAGICK_PREFIX  = `Magick-config --prefix`.strip!
MAGICK_VERSION = `Magick-config --version`.strip!.split(/\s/).first

RGB_COLOR_PROFILE = "#{MAGICK_PREFIX}/share/ImageMagick-#{MAGICK_VERSION}/config/sRGB.icm"
```

Comment: Those files can be in any number of places. See https://imagemagick.org/script/resources.php. Set up $MAGICK_CONFIGURE_PATH and it will be the first place looked. Next it will look at $PREFIX/etc/ImageMagick-7. Same for IM 6 -- $PREFIX/etc/ImageMagick-6.

Answer (score 1):

I have no perfect anwser, but you can

```
$ convert -list color | grep Path: | awk '{print $2}'
/usr/lib/ImageMagick-6.3.7/config/colors.xml
```

If response is [built-in] try another -list value.

Answer (score 1):

try these and parse stdout / stderr. the first one should work always

```
convert -debug configure rose: info:

convert -list configure
```

Comment: muchas gracias!
`convert -list configure` did the work